# Очищение у пользователя столбца status

Tags: php, mysql

Мне нужно, чтобы из бд Выводился список всех пользователей, у которых в столбце status прописано значение admin, при этом нужно чтобы рядом была кнопка удаления пользователя, которая очищала бы у него столбец status.

Comment: Если вы не можете решить такую задачу сами, может не стоит этим заниматься вообще?

Comment: в общем select и рядом кнопка с update

Comment: Manitikyl, в том то и дело, я начинающий, могу и имею права не знать элементарных вещей

Comment: @НикитаЧереп Не имеешь ты права не знать элементарных вещей. Как новичок ты должен показать нам код, что ты делал, что не получилось, что-то дообъяснить тебе. А у тебя вообще ноль. Есть простая задача, а ты ее сделать не можешь, тут дело не в том, новичок ты или нет, просто ленивый. Почитай любой учебник по пхп даже, и после прочтения 90% вопроса отпадет само собой.